# quantmod finance.yahoo reliable way to adjustOHLC

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

I am trying to get the functions getSymbols and adjustOHLC from the quantmod package to retrieve data from finance.yahoo.com and adjust it by splits and dividends. Unfortunately, it doesn't work consistently. I haven't tried to adjust by the Adj-column, since this would result in loss of precision (from the help of ?adjustOHLC).

```
library(quantmod)

symbols <- c("ADP", "GE", "KBH", "MO", "MMM", "MSFT")
from <- "2000-01-01"
to <- "2013-12-31"

# retrieve data and plot unadjusted close price
par (mfrow=c(2,3))
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  getSymbols(symbols[i], from=from, auto.assign=TRUE)
  plot(Cl(get(symbols[i])), main=symbols[i], type="p", pch=20)
}

# adjust for splits and dividends
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  assign (symbols[i], adjustOHLC(get(symbols[i]), 
               adjust=c("split", "dividend"), 
               use.Adjusted=FALSE,
               symbol.name=symbols[i]))
}

# plot adjusted series
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  plot(Cl(get(symbols[i])), main=paste0(symbols[i],".adjusted"), type="p", pch=20)
}
```

### charts before adjustOHLC

[image: charts before adjustOHLC]

### charts after adjustOHLC

[image]

Interestingly, although there was a split at ADP (2007-04-02  4.5625), the time series seem to be adjusted in the first place. Other splits like at GE are not adjusted at all. Adjustment by dividends seem to work correctly.

I am using quantmod_0.4-0 with R 3.1.0 on Ubuntu.

Anybody can come up with a more robust solution?

Comment: try `getSymbols("GE", adjust=TRUE)`

Comment: I tried this, it leads to the same result as in my example

Comment: This was a bug in either quantmod or TTR (or both) that has been fixed in the R-Forge versions of the packages.  ADP still isn't right, but the "split" on 2007-04-02 seems to be a combined split+spin-off in the data, which makes it difficult to determine what the correct ratio should be.

Comment: With the current packages quantmod and TTR from R-Forge, the adjustment of the symbols I tried is correct, except ADP, which should not be adjusted. I can live with that. Is there any reason why the patched packages are not transfered to CRAN?